# Jackson skip field when creating JSON

Tags: java, jackson

I have a class like

```
public class MyPojo {
    String name,
    String age
    String sub
}
```

And map like

map("name":"john","age":21)

Using Jacksons `ObjectMapper`, I get a string like

```json
{
  "name": "john",
  "age": "21",
  "sub": null
}
```

but instead I want to exclude the `sub`:

```json
{
  "name": "john",
  "age": "21"
}
```

How can I do that and tell Jackson to skip `sub`?

**P.S.** Please keep in mind that I want to have ability to exclude `age` and include `sub` without changing the POJO class, so `@JsonIgnore` doesn't quite fit.

Comment: But sometimes i want to exclude age and include sub without changing pojo class

Comment: Based on what do you want to exclude those fields?

Comment: @Rick Based on map

Comment: Are you asking how to exclude null values? Then please [edit] your question to clarify and include the code where you transform the map into a String.

Comment: No not to exclude null values but to exclude which are not present in map

Comment: Do you want to serialize the map or the pojo? If you want to exclude properties based on the map, why don't you serialize the map directly? Seems like the obvious choice.

Comment: I want to serialize the map into pojo excluding attributes which are not present in map

Comment: Then what do you want the values in the pojo to be if not null?

Comment: Serialize the map into POJO? But the question talks about serializing the POJO into a JSON string? I'm more confused now than before. Jackson will already not populate fields/properties in the POJO if they are missing from the string.

Comment: @knittl we can make a custom serializer and incorporate that logic.

Comment: @AnkitSharma which logic? OP has failed so far to understandabily explain what "that logic" is.

Answer (score 0):

You can try this approach in order to avoid the **null attributes** in the final json.

I have used **`ObjectMapper`** object and *set the below property* to **avoid null attributes** in the json.

**`mapper.setSerializationInclusion(JsonInclude.Include.NON_NULL);`**

Code as follows:

**MyPojo.java**

```
    public class MyPojo {

    private String name;
    private String age;
    private String sub;

    public String getName() {
        return name;
    }

    public void setName(String name) {
        this.name = name;
    }

    public String getAge() {
        return age;
    }

    public void setAge(String age) {
        this.age = age;
    }

    public String getSub() {
        return sub;
    }

    public void setSub(String sub) {
        this.sub = sub;
    }

    @Override
    public String toString() {
        return "MyPojo{" +
                "name=" + name +
                ", age=" + age +
                ", sub=" + sub +
                '}';
    }
}
```

**Test.java**

```
public class Test {

public static void main(String[] args) throws JsonProcessingException {

    Map<String,String> inputMap = new HashMap<>();
    inputMap.put("age","21");
    inputMap.put("name","John");

    ObjectMapper mapper = new ObjectMapper();
    mapper.setSerializationInclusion(JsonInclude.Include.NON_NULL);

    MyPojo p = mapper.convertValue(inputMap,MyPojo.class);
    
    System.out.println(p);
    System.out.println(mapper.writeValueAsString(p));
}
```

}

**Output:**

```
MyPojo{name=John, age=21, sub=null}

{"name":"John","age":"21"}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use `java.util.Optional` in your `POJO` class. You can convert `Map` to `POJO` and after that serialise it ignoring `null-s`. `Optional` allows to distinguish `map.put("property", null)` from not setting `property` at all. See below example:

```java
import com.fasterxml.jackson.annotation.JsonInclude;
import com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.SerializationFeature;
import com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.json.JsonMapper;
import com.fasterxml.jackson.datatype.jdk8.Jdk8Module;
import lombok.AllArgsConstructor;
import lombok.Data;
import lombok.NoArgsConstructor;

import java.util.HashMap;
import java.util.Map;
import java.util.Optional;

public class DateApp {
    private final static JsonMapper JSON_MAPPER = JsonMapper.builder()
            .enable(SerializationFeature.INDENT_OUTPUT)
            .addModule(new Jdk8Module())
            .build();

    public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {
        Map<String, Object> map = new HashMap<>();
        map.put("name", "John");
        map.put("age", 21);

        MyPojo pojo = JSON_MAPPER.convertValue(map, MyPojo.class);
        System.out.println(pojo);

        System.out.println("JSON:");
        JSON_MAPPER.writeValue(System.out, pojo);
    }
}

@Data
@NoArgsConstructor
@AllArgsConstructor
@JsonInclude(JsonInclude.Include.NON_NULL)
class MyPojo {
    private Optional<String> name;
    private Optional<String> age;
    private Optional<String> sub;
}
```

Above code prints:

```
MyPojo(name=Optional[John], age=Optional[21], sub=null)
JSON:
{
  "name" : "John",
  "age" : "21"
}
```

Comment: What if, if my map is map=("name":"john","age":21,"sub":null) , i would expect sub attribute in output. And if map=("name":"john","age":21) then i would expect only name and john in output.I dont want to avoid null values instead i want to avoid attributes which are not present in map

Comment: @Geeth, it works like you described. Check it out.

Answer (score 0):

You can create your custom serializer.

Just include your **map** in the serializer code

```java
import com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.annotation.JsonSerialize;

@JsonSerialize(using = MyPojoSerializer.class)
public class MyPojo {
    String name;
    String age;
    String sub;
}
```

```java
import com.fasterxml.jackson.core.JsonGenerator;
import com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.JsonSerializer;
import com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.SerializerProvider;

public class MyPojoSerializer extends JsonSerializer<MyPojo> {

    @Override
    public void serialize(MyPojo myPojo, JsonGenerator jGen, SerializerProvider serializerProvider) throws IOException {
        jGen.writeStartObject();
        // Map map = ....
        for (final Field field : myPojo.getClass().getDeclaredFields()) {
            ReflectionUtils.makeAccessible(field);
            final String fieldName = field.getName();
            final Object fieldValue = ReflectionUtils.getField(field, myPojo);
            if (map.containsKey(fieldName)) {
                jGen.writeFieldName(fieldName);
                jGen.writeObject(fieldValue);
            }
        }
        jGen.writeEndObject();
    }
}
```